# Set border for each side of a range in different style without adding entry to history?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a conditional style for border, where each side has its own style if range is not empty, and remove border if range is empty.
So far, I have the following code:

```js
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range;
  if (e.value === undefined) /* cleared/undo */
  {
    range.setBorder(false /*top*/, null, null, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, null, null);
    // SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    range.setBorder(null, false /*left*/, null, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, null, null);
    // SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    range.setBorder(null, null, false /*bottom*/, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, null, null);
    // SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    range.setBorder(null, null, null, false /*right*/, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, null, null);
  }
  else
  {
    range.setBorder(true /*top*/, null, null, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, "red" /*color*/, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    range.setBorder(null, true /*left*/, null, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, "green" /*color*/, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    range.setBorder(null, null, true /*bottom*/, null, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, "blue" /*color*/, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    range.setBorder(null, null, null, true /*right*/, false /*vertical*/, false /*horizontal*/, "black" /*color*/, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
  }
}
```

There are several issues with this code:

1. when edited a range and it became not empty, it styles the border around of it, but in order to remove the changes I'd have to press undo several times.
2. when clearing a range, it only clears border on right side
3. if uncomment `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` lines - it works, but it seems adding new entry into undo history for each side (?), which means as soon as undo button hit, it clears all borders again, adding additional 4 entries, you have to quickly hit undo 5 times or it won't work. Basically it's impossible to use undo with this code.

So, my question is how can I properly set individual border style for each side and clear the style and if possible, without affecting undo history? for example if I entered a word into a cell, it would change border around the cell, clicking undo once would clear the cell and remove the border style at the same time.

Comment: One option might be instead of using the The Spreadsheet Service (Class SpreadsheetApp) use the Advanced Sheets Service (Class Sheets) but this way it will not possible to revert the changes using Undo.

Comment: I don't think you can do this unfortunately - why is the undo history important here?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou well, it's not _that_ important, but of course having 5 undo history for 1 action is quiet annoying...at least if I could distinguish between user clearing the range vs doing undo, I could make it usable... at the moment I'm checking `e.value` which is `undefined` when user does undo and when clearing with `del` key

Comment: I think the issue here is `clicking undo once would clear the cell and remove the border style at the same time` - if you're entering a word and changing the border style separately then this will inherently be two undo steps. Each `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` call forces all pending changes to the spreadsheet, so I would infer here that each call forces creation of a new undo step.